# Bootstrap tabs not working for a view with two partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a main view which has two tabs. The first tab is the default tab and should display the first partial view and the second tab should display the second partial view. While I am getting that to work properly, I am not able to get the tab highlighted for the particular selected tab.

My controller.

```
public ActionResult Contact(int condition=0)
    {

        if(condition==0)
            ViewBag.Message = "Tab1";
        else
            ViewBag.Message = "Tab2";

        ViewBag.Condition = condition;
        return View();
    }
```

My View

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>


<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tab1","Contact", new { condition=0})</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tab2", "Contact", new { condition = 1 })</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    @if (ViewBag.Condition == 0)
    {
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="Tab1">
        @Html.Partial("_Partial1")
    </div>
    }
    else
    {
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="Tab2">
        @Html.Partial("_Partial2")
    </div>
    }
</div>

</div>
```

EDIT 1: As suggested by an answer does not solve the problem.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>


<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tab1","Contact", new { condition=0}, new { @class = ViewBag.Condition == 0 ? "active" : "" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tab2", "Contact", new { condition = 1 }, new { @class = ViewBag.Condition == 1 ? "active" : "" })</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    @if (ViewBag.Condition == 0)
    {
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="Tab1">
        @Html.Partial("_Partial1")
    </div>
    }
    else
    {
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="Tab2">
        @Html.Partial("_Partial2")
    </div>
    }
</div>

</div>
```

EDIT 2:

```
   <div id="tabs">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

        <li class="nav active">@Html.ActionLink("Tab1", "Contact", new { condition = 0 }, new { @id = "Tab1", data_toggle = "tab" })</li>
        <li class="nav">@Html.ActionLink("Tab2", "Contact", new { condition = 1 }, new { @id = "Tab2", data_toggle = "tab" })</li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content">

    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Tab1">
        @Html.Partial("_Partial1")
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Tab2">
        @Html.Partial("_Partial2")
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

I have changed the code to be based on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79zjyd6L/1/)
Does not make much difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there are better ways of doing it but this solution works for me. I just check the Viewbag everytime and set the class of li active based on the check. This way I end up setting the right li element even though the screen has a call to the action method on tab change.

```
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    @if (ViewBag.Condition == 0)
    {
        <li class="nav active">@Html.ActionLink("Tab1", "Contact", new { condition = 0 }, new { @id = "Tab1" })</li>
        <li class="nav">
            @Html.ActionLink("Tab2", "Contact", new { condition = 1 }, new{@id = "Tab2"})
        </li>
    }
    else if (ViewBag.Condition == 1)
    {
        <li class="nav">@Html.ActionLink("Tab1", "Contact", new { condition = 0 }, new { @id = "Tab1"})</li>
        <li class="nav active">@Html.ActionLink("Tab2", "Contact", new { condition = 1 }, new { @id = "Tab2"})</li>
    }
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    @if (ViewBag.Condition == 0)
    {
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Tab1">
            @Html.Partial("_Partial1")
        </div>
    }
    else if (ViewBag.Condition == 1)
    {
        <div class="tab-pane fade  in active" id="Tab2">
            @Html.Partial("_Partial2")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tab1", "Contactme", new { condition = 0 })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tab2", "Contactme", new { condition = 1 })</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        @if (ViewBag.Condition == 0)
        {
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="Tab1">
               @Html.Partial("_Partial1")
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="Tab2">
                @Html.Partial("_Partial2")
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I could not find the difference between my code and yours. Can you please point out what you have corrected?

Comment: you had forgotten to close ending div at the end "</div>"

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out but you could have edited the question instead of posting it as an answer as I don't think you are adding anything substantial to consider it as an answer.

Comment: you are right but my reputation is lower than 50 i cant comment at first